# "Script not found or unable to stat" в логах Apache

Tags: apache

Здравствуйте!

В последнее время сервер стал очень долго отвечать на запросы, более 10 секунд (приходят сообщения с яндекс.метрики), в связи с этим, заглянул в логи и увидел следующее:

[image]

Если "no acceptable variant..." вроде как лечится добавлением в httpd.conf следующего:

```
<Files "*.php">
MultiviewsMatch Any
</Files>
```

То что делать со "script not found..." и что это означает? И связано ли это с долгими ответами сервера?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

script not found... => скрипт не найден, нет?

Судя по логу, у Вас apache обращается к php по некоему адресу (скрин), но самого php там нет.

Вы уверены, что он там? :-)

**Обновление**

Ну, начнем с того, что ничего не рождается на пустом месте - если apache правильно настроен, то да - надо включать паранойю (немного), Вас вполне могут пытаться "сломать".

Как вариант - поставьте туда "заглушку" - скрипт, который ничего не делает.

**Обновление**

Тут и без статьи можно обойтись - просто поместите пустой файл по тому адресу, который у Вас просят:

```
/opt/bitnami/apache2/cgi-bin/php
/opt/bitnami/apache2/cgi-bin/php5
/opt/bitnami/apache2/cgi-bin/php.cgi
/opt/bitnami/apache2/cgi-bin/php4
```

И, по сути, все, теперь, когда у нас что-то попросят, мы это отдадим, но ничего не произойдет.

После можно начинать копать - почему у нас это вообще попросили?

Comment: Само php лежит в другой директории, в директории, куда он обращается, лежат: php-cgi и php-cgi.bin    
На других форумах говорят, что, возможно, это атаки на сервер, но так конечного ответа там и не появилось.

Comment: В администрировании я новичок, если возможно, дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на дельную статью по созданию "заглушек".

Comment: Спасибо, начну с этого, потом уже дальше начну разбираться. :)

Answer (score 2):

Чувствую, что скриптов-то этих там не должно быть. Поэтому два варианта:

- кто-то пытается залить скрипт и исполнить его;
- просто дедосят.

Comment: Тоже такие подозрения.